# Prepared statements in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

Trying to figure out how to make prepared statements work in plpgsql in order to sanitize my code.

```
PREPARE statements(text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text, text) AS
                        'SELECT
                            *
                        FROM
                            articles
                        WHERE
                            ' || $1 || ' AND
                            ' || $2 || ' AND
                            primary_category LIKE ''' || $3 || ''' AND
                            ' || $4 || ' AND
                            ' || $5 || ' AND
                            ' || $6 || ' AND
                            ' || $7 || ' AND
                            ' || $8 || ' AND
                            ' || $9 || ' AND
                            ' || $10 || ' AND
                            ' || $11 || ' AND
                            is_template = ' || §12 || ' AND
                            status <> ''DELETED''
                        ORDER BY ' || $13 || ' LIMIT 500';

                    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE statements(search_term, publication_date_query, category_filter, tags_query, districts_query, capability_query, push_notification_query, distance_query, revision_by, publication_priority_query, status_query, only_templates, order_by);
```

The above code returns

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'SELECT
                        *
                    FROM
                        articles
                    WHERE
                        '"
LINE 67:      'SELECT
```

I declade my variables like so:

```
DECLARE
tags_query text := 'true';
BEGIN
        IF char_length(search_term) > 0 THEN
            order_by := 'ts_rank_cd(textsearchable_index_col, to_tsquery(''' || search_term || ':*''))+GREATEST(0,(-1*EXTRACT(epoch FROM age(last_edited)/86400))+60)/60 DESC';
            search_term := 'to_tsquery(''' || search_term || ':*'') @@ textsearchable_index_col';
        ELSE
            search_term := 'true';
        END IF;
...
```

I am new at this, please don't freak out immediately, if it is something silly, i did not notice.

Edit: PostgreSQL Version 9.6

Edit: I am aware of the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-prepare.html).

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to sanitize my user input. @UsagiMiyamoto I read, that prepared statements are the way to go VS sql injection.

Comment: You shouldn't need concatenation to construct your prepared statement. In the linked doc, see how in the first example `$1` to `$4` are used as-is in the statement. I'm also pretty sure that you can't provide whole expressions as parameters (i.e. `$1` = `COLUMN=VALUE` and `$1 AND...` in your statement) but should only provide values (i.e. `$1` = `VALUE` and `COLUMN=$1 AND...` in your statement), however I can't find it specified in the doc you linked so I might be wrong.

Comment: That "prepeared statement" is not the one in the SQL engine, but in a high level program, that uses the database. EG in your Java or PHP program.

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto how can you be sure of that? Prepared Statements are a thing DB-side too. Although I agree you generally create them from an external application.

Comment: As per your linked docs: "A prepared statement is a server-side object that can be used to optimize performance." It is not about SQL injection protection...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto with our stack, i have to catch it via SQL. There is no high lvl program.

Comment: Well, concatenating strings would not do it anyway...

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto pretty sure they're talking of the SGBD as a server as opposed to the application (and others) as client, meaning the PreparedStatement is stored in the DB rather than just known and used by the clients

Comment: @Aaron Exactly. I have to catch it in my DB via PostgreSQL. I read, that prepared statements are the stuff that i need to use.

Comment: thank you guys for taking the time.

Comment: What do you mean by "catch" ? Note that "Prepared statements only last for the duration of the current database session." so if you create them with an SQL client then hope for your application to have access to them you'll be disappointed. That's why Usagi mentions that they are to be created by your application, which should have its own framework rather than asking you to execute PREPARE queries

Comment: See: http://bobby-tables.com/postgresql

Comment: I just read that you had no higher level language in your stack, so my previous comment kinda falls flat. If you just have `psql` or other basic SQL client they will have to run the `PREPARE` query before being able to run associated `EXECUTE` queries. It would be easy to have a script initiating a connection to your DB and running the PREPARE statement before resuming its normal operations (whether it is other pre-defined queries or an interactive session) ; other than that, Usagi's link seems like a nice resource to learn about their syntax :)

Answer (score 0):

I see more issues.

1. PLpgSQL doesn't support explicitly prepared commands - so SQL `EXECUTE` command is different than PLpgSQL `EXECUTE` command. Parameter of PLpgSQL `EXECUTE` command is SQL string - not name of prepared command. There are not clean way, how to execute SQL explicitly prepared command from PLpgSQL. So, combination `PREPARE cmd(); EXECUTE cmd()` in PLpgSQL has not any sense.
2. Parameter of prepared statement should by clean value - it cannot be used inside apostrophes. ` ' $n ' is another nonsense. Just $n is safe. ' $n ' means string " $n " what is probably different, than you are expecting.